# Export data from Redshift to R via S3

Tags: r, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to export table from Redshift to R in 2 steps (in an automated way):

1. Redshift -> S3 bucket
2. S3 bucket -> R

Data in S3 bucket are stored in multiple files (+ manifest file). Is there a package, that I may use to load these files from S3 to a single `data.frame`/`data.table` in R environment?

Comment: You can achieve step 2 using https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use R odbc?